# Overloading buck regulator

Tags: buck, load

I'm having a hard time explaining to myself why the output voltage of a buck regulator drops at the load when the load pulls more current than the max limit of the buck regulator.

Can someone help me understand this by assuming let's say I have a 3.3V buck regulator circuit that is rated for up to 2A. What happens to the buck topology components' voltages/currents when the load tries to pull 3A instead that causes the voltage output of regulator to drop?

Does same thing happen if I use a linear regulator instead, meaning output voltage drop during overloading?

Thanks,
Dan

Comment: Everything drops in output voltage when the current gets too high. If it did not you would have a perpetual motion machine that produces energy from nothing.

Comment: If you pull paper too hard it rips. Something gives either catastrophically or benignly. What happens when you car wheels cannot supply the torque to drive up a hill?

Comment: Clearly explained it guys. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does same thing happen if I use a linear regulator instead, meaning output voltage drop during overloading?

Everything drops in output voltage when the current gets too high. If it did not you would have a perpetual motion machine that produces energy from nothing.

> Can someone help me understand this by assuming let's say I have a 3.3V buck regulator circuit that is rated for up to 2A. What happens to the buck topology components' voltages/currents when the load tries to pull 3A instead that causes the voltage output of regulator to drop?

- Inductors saturate when the current gets too high and they stop doing their inductive thing
- Transistor switches saturate and can't pass more current to the output.
- Any and all resistances in the current path will produce increasing voltage drops as current increases to the point where they output voltage as dropped intolerably low.
- The capacitor is too small to supply enough charge to "tide things over" for the frequency at which the converter is operating at; The frequency being how often that capacitor is topped up.

Comment: That perfectly explains it, thanks DKNguyen.

Answer (score 1):

mainly the inductor can only store so much energy, for a given input voltage and a given ON_TIME.